# Dropdownlist onChange pass URL MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, onchange

I using dropdown list and passing the url onchange event something like below

```
@onchange = "windows.location.href='Url.Action('Index', 'StudentManagement')?Id='this.options[this.selectedIndex].value+'&isDropdownValue=true'"
```

but while loading the View I am getting syntax error because url is getting converted as below

```
onchange="windows.location.href=&#39;Url.Action(&#39;Index&#39;, &#39;StudentManagement&#39;)?Id=&#39;this.options[this.selectedIndex].value+&#39;&amp;isDropdownValue=true&#39;"
```

Someone please suggest me proper way of passing multiple parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tried code as below and working fine

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StudentId, Model.LstStudent, "-- Select --", new { id = "ddlStudent", @class = "form-control" })

$("#ddlStudent").change(function () {
    var selectedStudentVal = $("#ddlStudentoption:selected").val();
    window.location.replace("/StudentManagement/Index?Id=" + selectedStudentVal + "&isddlValue=true");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
 var action = Url.Action("Index", "StudentManagement", new { Id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,isDropdownValue=true });
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YourModelName, Model.list, new{@class = "form-control",@onchange = "window.location.href='"+action+"'"});
```

Comment: if you will not use @ before URL and you will get URL is undefiend

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: Why won't you use @?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting query string like above because,  single quote you mentioned  had converted to its equivalent Ascii code along with other value.

**To Avoid that:**

In razor view of Mvc ,you should always use @ character for the server side code, in your case Url is a server side code.

**so your query string will look like:**

```
@onchange = "windows.location.href='@Url.Action('Index', 'StudentManagement')?Id='this.options[this.selectedIndex].value'&isDropdownValue=true'"
```

And also after the id value you no need the + symbol, it will automatically concatenate.

Hope the code will surely solve your problem ,kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks
karthik